# Problems ignoring columns when processing a text file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file that has 8 columns. I am trying to write a script that ignores the first 6 columns and puts the last 2 columns into a new text file. I wrote some code for it but it is just producing a blank text file. Basically I tried to store the numbers in the first 6 columns in dummy variables and just ignore them. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
void allNuclei()
{
  std::ifstream in("Zr/Zr_0.txt");
  if (!in.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "File is not exist" << std::endl;
      return;

    }

  int p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, A, N;
  in >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 >> p4 >> p5 >> p6 >> A >> N;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;
  while(in>>p1 && in>> p2 && in>>p3 && in>>p4 && in>>p5 && in>>p6 && in >> A && in >> N){
    vec.push_back((std::make_pair(A, N)));
  }

  ofstream m;
  m.open("All_Zr.txt");
  cout<<"starting fill"<<endl;
  for(int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++){
    m << vec[i].first << " " << vec[i].second << endl;
  }

}
```

So basically a file that looks like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Will make a file that looks like this:

7 8

Comment: You either forgot a `vec.push_back((std::make_pair(A, N)));` before the loop, or you forgot to erase the `in >> ...` line before the loop. Voting to close as typo

Comment: You discard the entire first row.

Comment: @scohe001 Well I don't think I need a vec.push_back before the loop because I want it to loop through each row of the text file and then push_back only the ints in the last two columns. And when I delete the in >> ... before the loop it doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @AndyG Where would the in >> p1 >> ... statement go?

Comment: @scohe001 It creates a blank text file. Nothing was written into it

Comment: Swapping your input and output streams for just standard in and standard out, I can't reproduce that: https://ideone.com/86dNNJ

Comment: Well it is around 1 million rows so with cin don't I need to enter it by hand?

Comment: I can't write an example with files on ideone. But file streams should function the same as cin/cout here. That was just an example to say that I don't see what you're claiming is happening. So clearly something is missing in your explanation. Have you checked that filestream `m` is actually good? That you have write access, etc.?

Comment: Yea I am not sure why this is not working. The text file being produced is just completely empty and I made a print statement to check just now and it says the vector is empty. So the problem is definitely in the loop or in the way I am processing the file, do you know another way to do this?

Comment: When you test with a file that looks exactly like what you say in your question (just `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`) does it work? Could it be that your real file is in badly formatted?

Comment: Yes I just tried it and it does work. I just figured out the problem. The first 6 columns are all doubles so it wasn't processing I didn't even realize that. Changing int to double solved the issue thanks for your help.

Comment: That sounds like a badly formatted file given the specifications you gave us :) For next time, be sure your simplified example matches your actual data. Glad it's all working!